# Unity C# How to set text as XML component?

Tags: c#, xml, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a quiz game and have just had a question answered about an XML connection error. This has been resolved but now I cannot work out why my text is not displaying the questions and answers from the XML file. I followed this question to make my code for the XML connection and most of the rest of the code. http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/639381/too-much-prefab-for-question-quiz-games.html

Here is my code that I am having trouble with:

```
[SerializeField]
private TextAsset questionDataXMLFile; 
private QuestionData questionData; 
private Question currentQuestion; 
public Text answerAText;
public Text answerBText;
public Text answerCText;
public Text question; 

void Start(){
    questionData = QuestionData.LoadFromText (questionDataXMLFile.text);
}

public void SetNewQuestion(){
    int q = Random.Range (0, questionData.questions.Count - 1);
    currentQuestion = questionData.questions [q]; 

    question.text = currentQuestion.questionText; 
    answerAText.text = currentQuestion.answerA;
    answerBText.text = currentQuestion.answerB;
    answerCText.text = currentQuestion.answerC;
}

public bool CorrectAnswerSelected(int selectedAnswerID){
    return selectedAnswerID == currentQuestion.correctAnswerID;
}

public void isACorrect(){
    if (currentQuestion.correctAnswerID == 0){
        //user got it right!
    }
    else { 
        //user got it wrong!
    }
}
public void isBCorrect(){
    if (currentQuestion.correctAnswerID == 1){
        //user got it right!
    }
    else { 
        //user got it wrong!
    }
}
public void isCCorrect(){
    if (currentQuestion.correctAnswerID == 2){
        //user got it right!
    }
    else { 
        //user got it wrong!
    }
}
```

I think the problem is with the:

```
question.text = currentQuestion.questionText;
```

and the same with setting the answer texts. 
On the other tutorial, it says to use code such as: 
             // add code here to set text values of your Question GameObject
             // e.g. GetComponent().Text =     currentQuestion.questionText;
         }

But I'm not sure how to do this and what values to use etc.

Here is the c# file where I access the XML file:

```
[XmlRoot("Questions")] 
public class QuestionData { 
    [XmlArray("Questions")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Question")]
    public List<Question>
    questions = new List<Question>();

    public static QuestionData LoadFromText(string text){
        try{
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(QuestionData));
            return serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(text)) as QuestionData;
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            UnityEngine.Debug.LogError("Exception loading question data: " + e);
            return null; 
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the XML file with some test questions in:

```
<Questions>

<Question>
<questionText>What is the capital city of France?</questionText>
<answerA>London</answerA>
<answerB>Paris</answerB>
<answerC>Rome</answerC>
<correctAnswerID>1</correctAnswerID>
</Question>

<Question> 
<questionText>What is the capital city of England?</questionText>
<answerA>London</answerA>
<answerB>Paris</answerB>
<answerC>Rome</answerC>
<correctAnswerID>0</correctAnswerID>
</Question>

</Questions>
```

Comment: Where do you declare and initialize `question`?

Comment: @GunnarB. I have edited my question to show all of the code I am working with. I hope this makes my question more clear

Comment: The rest of the first script is more important. I looked at the other scripts over in the link.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, completely missed the first part of my code when copying it over. It is all there now @GunnarB.

Comment: Ok, how does the user select an answer? Are answerA-CText text elements of a button (UI button I mean)?

Comment: If so, you can simply drag and drop them into the variables in the inspector.

Comment: Yes they are text elements on buttons and I have dragged and dropped them into the inspector but they still don't show up for some reason and neither does the question, which has also been dragged and dropped. @GunnarB.

Comment: Does the text get set on runtime? You can check that in the inspector.

Comment: Yes, they are set at runtime but it just does not show up on the screen as having been set to the question and answers on the xml file

Comment: Hmm, I try to recreate that, but the XML reading doesn't work for, just reads empty.

Comment: Could the issue be in the second piece of code in my question instead then?

Comment: I have my first piece of code in a script file attached to an empty game object with all the texts and xml file linked in the inspector

Comment: Add a `SetNewQuestion();` at the end of `Start()`, after loading the xml into `questionData`. Do you get an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`? If so, the reading didn't work.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what happened, does this mean there's something wrong with the XML file or the way I tried to retrieve the text from the file?

Comment: Yes, the list `Questions` in `QuestionData` is empty after reading.

Comment: Any way of sorting this?

Comment: I'm having a look at this. I'm not familiar with xml reading.

Comment: Thank you, anything you can do would mean a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I got it to work with these changes:

Change the question struct to this:

```
public class Question
{
    [XMLElement("questionText")]
    public string questionText;
    public string answerA;
    public string answerB;
    public string answerC;
    public int correctAnswerID;
}
```

Surround the stuff in the xml file with another block like this:

```
<QuestionsCollection>
  <Questions>
    <Question>
      <questionText>What is the capital city of France?</questionText>
      <answerA>London</answerA>
      <answerB>Paris</answerB>
      <answerC>Rome</answerC>
      <correctAnswerID>1</correctAnswerID>
    </Question>

    <Question> 
      <questionText>What is the capital city of England?</questionText>
      <answerA>London</answerA>
      <answerB>Paris</answerB>
      <answerC>Rome</answerC>
      <correctAnswerID>0</correctAnswerID>
    </Question>
  </Questions>
</QuestionsCollection>
```

Change

```
[XmlRoot("Questions")] 
public class QuestionData
```

to

```
[XmlRoot("QuestionsCollection")]
public class QuestionData
```

EDIT:
One flaw still in there: questionText is Null this way. Need to have a look at that.

EDIT2:
Got that fixed too. `[XMLAttribute("questionText")]` needs to be `[XMLElement("questionText")]`. Changed that block above.

EDIT3:
Some further additions:
Remove the `-1` from Random.Range, integer is inclusive/exclusive.

For the button click do this:

```
public void checkAnswer(int answerID)
{
    if(answerID == currentQuestion.correctAnswerID)
    {
        // answer was correct
        Debug.Log("correct");
    }
    else
    {
        // answer was wrong
        Debug.Log("wrong");
    }
    SetNewQuestion();
}
```

Give all the buttons a `OnClick`-event in the inspector and pass the index of the button (matching the answer ids). Example for Button3 here (the script is on the `QuestionDisplay` gameobject:
[image]

Comment: Thank you, I am so happy with this solution! It is exactly what I wanted!! You are amazing.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but do you know a way of ensuring each question is only shown once each but it still be random?

Comment: @KatyJones Just remove the question from `questionData.questions` at the end of `SetNewQuestion` -> `questionsData.questions.RemoveAt(q);`