# XmlDocument.LoadXML NullReferenceExcpetion when it is assigned in the Unity Inspector

Tags: xml, unity-game-engine, xml-parsing

I have an XML database (that is custom made), that I am trying to load in Unity3D.
I have a public TextAsset that I am assigning in the inspector to equal my XML Database.
When I run my script, it throws a NullReferenceException, on line XMLDocument.loadxml().
When I simplify this, and use just a simple string in XML format, and change it to XMLDocument.Load() (with the same tags, and data) it works. This is much less than desirable for writing though.

```
public TextAsset enemyXML;  
This one works--> //public string enemyXml = "<Enemy><EnemyName> Scale </EnemyName><EnemyID> 001 </EnemyID><EnemySpriteTag> Scale </EnemySpriteTag><EnemyBrawn>8  </EnemyBrawn><EnemyBrisk> 8 </EnemyBrisk><EnemyBrains>8</EnemyBrains>   <EnemyBravery> 10 </EnemyBravery><EnemyAbilitySet1> Scale </EnemyAbilitySet1>   <EnemyAbilitySet2> None </EnemyAbilitySet2><EnemyAbilitySet3> None    </EnemyAbilitySet3> <EnemyAbilitySet4> None </EnemyAbilitySet4></Enemy>"; 

XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
This one works--> //xmlDoc.Load(new StringReader(enemyXml));
xmlDoc.LoadXml(enemyXml.text);
XmlNodeList enemyList = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Enemy");  
foreach (XmlNode enemyInfo in enemyList)
        {
        XmlNodeList EnemyContent = enemyInfo.ChildNodes;
        enemyDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>(); //in Items tag, first tag, text associated with
        foreach (XmlNode content in EnemyContent)
        {
            switch(content.Name)//must contain all things for each item
            {
                case "EnemyName":
                    enemyDictionary.Add("EnemyName", content.InnerText);
                    break;
                case "EnemyID":
                    enemyDictionary.Add("EnemyID", content.InnerText);
                    break;
                case "EnemySpriteTag":
                    enemyDictionary.Add("EnemySpriteTag", content.InnerText);
                    break;
                case "EnemyBrawn":
                    enemyDictionary.Add("EnemyBrawn", content.InnerText);
                    break;
                case "EnemyBrisk":
                    enemyDictionary.Add("EnemyBrisk", content.InnerText);
                    break;
                case "EnemyBrains":
                    enemyDictionary.Add("EnemyBrains", content.InnerText);
                    break;
                case "EnemyBravery":
                    enemyDictionary.Add("EnemyBravery", content.InnerText);
                    break;
                case "EnemyAbilitySet1":
                    enemyDictionary.Add("EnemyAbilitySet1", content.InnerText);
                    break;
                case "EnemyAbilitySet2":
                    enemyDictionary.Add("EnemyAbilitySet2", content.InnerText);
                    break;
                case "EnemyAbilitySet3":
                    enemyDictionary.Add("EnemyAbilitySet3", content.InnerText);
                    break;
                case "EnemyAbilitySet4":
                    enemyDictionary.Add("EnemyAbilitySet4", content.InnerText);
                    break;
            }
        }
        EnemyDictionList.Add(enemyDictionary);
    }
```

That's all the relevant code I could thing of.
The Custom XML file, is wrapped in  with the above string being shoved into the the middle.
Am I just missing a spelling, or something? I've been very lost for a few days now, and had no luck searching.

If needed in an edit I can include the class BaseEnemy.

Edit:
This also works with the rest of my code as well.

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(Path.Combine(Application.dataPath,"RPGEnemyDatabase.xml"));
```

Though, trying to assign it in the inspector, or trying to say enemyXML.text, does not.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using System.IO;

...

XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

string xmlContent = File.ReadAllText(enemyXML);

xmlDoc.LoadXML(enemyXML);
```

Edit:
You might want to have a look at my solution here: [Unity C# How to set text as XML component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36344304/unity-c-sharp-how-to-set-text-as-xml-component)

Comment: I played around with that a little bit. So far, to no avail. What I have found to work, is to not assign it in the unity editor. If I go straight to xmlDoc.Load("FilePath"); it works.
Could this be a problem with the Unity Editor?

Comment: I don't think so. The other solution I posted (that is basically the version of CloudSL) that uses a `XmlSerializer` also uses a `public TextAsset` that is populated via the inspector. What might be a problem is actually the structure of the XML file. That other version needs this type of nested structure to work -> `<EnemyCollection> <Enemies> <Enemy> stuff`

Comment: With CloudSL's solution, I am getting a NullReferenceException on the xml.text line. This includes the changes made in the Xml file. 
The confusion for me here is, if I just input the path to the file, and use xmldocument.load it works perfectly.
But trying to load it as a textasset, i get errors.
Is there a reason to not just get the path and progress from there?

Comment: For your solution it's probably not a big deal, but in general it's easier to reassign a field via the inspector then changing a code line when you re-structure your folder. If `xml.text` gives you a NullReferenceException that means that the public field is null (= has nothing assign to it). You did drag the xml from the assets folder into that field in the inspector right?

Comment: Yup. It has the name in the slot, and everything. If I click play it's there, when I exit play mode it's still there. So, I didn't assign it in play mode.
This is a weird bug to me.

Answer (score 0):

XmlFile

```
<EnemyCollection>
   <Enemies>
      <Enemy>
         <EnemyName>Scale</EnemyName>
         <EnemyID>001</EnemyID>
         <EnemySpriteTag>Scale</EnemySpriteTag>
         <EnemyBrawn>8</EnemyBrawn>
         <EnemyBrisk>8</EnemyBrisk>
         <EnemyBrains>8</EnemyBrains>   
         <EnemyBravery>10</EnemyBravery>
         <EnemyAbilitySet1>Scale</EnemyAbilitySet1>   
         <EnemyAbilitySet2>None</EnemyAbilitySet2>
         <EnemyAbilitySet3>None</EnemyAbilitySet3> 
         <EnemyAbilitySet4>None</EnemyAbilitySet4>
      </Enemy>
   </Enemies>
</EnemyCollection>
```

Create another class file with

```
public class Enemy {

    public string EnemyName { get; set; }
    public string EnemyID { get; set; }
    public string EnemySpriteTag { get; set; }
    public string EnemyBrawn { get; set; }
    public string EnemyBrisk { get; set; }
    public string EnemyBrains { get; set; }
    public string EnemyBravery { get; set; }
    public string EnemyAbilitySet1 { get; set; }
    public string EnemyAbilitySet2 { get; set; }
    public string EnemyAbilitySet3 { get; set; }
    public string EnemyAbilitySet4 { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("EnemyCollection")]
public class EnemiesContainer
{
    [XmlArray("Enemies"), XmlArrayItem("Enemy")]
    public Enemy[] enemies;

    public static EnemiesContainer LoadFromText(string text)
    {
       var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(EnemiesContainer));
       return serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(text)) as EnemiesContainer;
    }

}
```

And last in the main class where you retrieve the xml data, you will still be reading the xml from a TextAsset

```
public TextAsset xml;

void Start () {

    string xmlContent = xml.text;
    var enemyData = EnemiesContainer.LoadFromText(xmlContent);


    foreach (var enemy in enemyData.enemies)
    {
        Debug.Log(enemy.EnemyName);
        Debug.Log(enemy.EnemyID);
        Debug.Log(enemy.EnemySpriteTag);
        Debug.Log(enemy.EnemyBrawn);
        Debug.Log(enemy.EnemyBrisk);
        Debug.Log(enemy.EnemyBrains);
        //...
    }

}
```

for further reference
http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Saving_and_Loading_Data:_XmlSerializer

Comment: Thank you for the reference link. I couldn't find that on my own. Not sure why, maybe I was being to specific in my Google-fu.
This method appears to return an enemy object for each tag Enemy, in tag Enemies. Is that correct? Or will I have to parse each one into an Enemy(Class) object?

Comment: Correct, This will return an array of enemy objects, which will contain all the Enemy tags which were within the Enemies tag.

Comment: To answer the question of why the NullReferenceException if you use textAsset  with xml assigned from inspector, are you by chance initializing the textAsset at `Start()` as `textAsset = new TextAsset()` if so this will overwrite the xmlfile that you added from inspector as a null new object. If you remove this particular line it should work.

Comment: I am not ever resetting it to a default sadly. That would be a nice fix. 
I have another script that follows almost exactly what I was doing, just with different tags, and that one works. Is there a particular downside to going down the path route?

Comment: after assigning the xml to textasset in inspector, go to play mode and check the inspector again to see if the file is still assigned or is it `None (Text Asset)`.

Comment: It stays assigned. That was one of my first thoughts.